# How do I make EF EntityType.GetProperty Eager load?

Tags: entity-framework-6

I am using the following code snippet to save a modified entity in my repository

```
object id1 = item.GetProperty("Id");
T originalEntity = dbSet.Find(id1); // but this doesnt update navigation properties
((DbContext)context).Entry(originalEntity).CurrentValues.SetValues(item);
navProps = GetNavigationProperties(originalEntity);
foreach (PropertyInfo navProp in navProps)
{
    //Set originalEntity prop value to modifiedEntity value
    var newval = (LoggedEntity)navProp.GetValue(item);
    object entity = null;
    if (newval != null)
    {
        Type tp = navProp.PropertyType;
        DbSet entities = ((DbContext)context).Set(tp);
        entity = entities.Find(newval.Id);
    }
    navProp.SetValue(originalEntity, entity);
}
```

which calls

```
public List<PropertyInfo> GetNavigationProperties(T entity)
{
    Type t = entity.GetType();
    ObjectContext objectContex = ((IObjectContextAdapter)((DbContext)context)).ObjectContext;

    EntityType elementType = objectContex.CreateObjectSet<T>().EntitySet.ElementType;

    var properties = new List<PropertyInfo>();
    Type entityType = entity.GetType();
    foreach (NavigationProperty navigationProperty in elementType.NavigationProperties)
    {
        PropertyInfo prop = entityType.GetProperty(navigationProperty.Name);
        properties.Add(prop);
    }
    return properties;
}
```

However I have a problem when I want to set the navigation property to null.
The changes simply don't save.

The answer is explained [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12828739/entity-framework-set-navigation-property-to-null)

Which points out that the navigation properties need to be eager loaded.

How do I modify my GetNavigationProperties procedure to eager load?

Answer (score 0):

I inserted the following line
    originalEntity.GetProperty(navProp.Name);

before 
    navProp.SetValue(originalEntity, entity);

and now the code works if entity is null