# How to syncronize records with Entity Framework Core for one to many relation during the update operation? Not add a new entity, just syncronize

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have the following entities: `PushTemplate` and `PushTemplateMessage`. One `PushTemplate` can have many `PushTemplateMessage`s. I have repositories for this. All works for the create operation. But problem starts when I try to update `PushTemplate` and set new text for messages. Insetad of an update I see new one `PushTemplateMessage`. I'll show my code.

Entity `PushTemplate`:

```
public class PushTemplate
{
    public int PushTemplateId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public List<PushTemplateMessage> Messages { get; set; }

    public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }

    public PushTemplate()
    {
        CreatedAt = DateTime.UtcNow;
    }
}
```

Entity `PushTemplateMessage`:

```
public class PushTemplateMessage
{
    public int PushTemplateMessageId { get; set; }

    public string PushTitle { get; set; }
    public string PushMessage { get; set; }
    public PushTemplate PushTemplate { get; set; }
}
```

Repository `PushTemplateRepository`:

```
public class PushTemplateRepository : IPushTemplateRepository
{
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _applicationContext;

    public PushTemplateRepository(ApplicationDbContext applicationContext)
    {
        _applicationContext = applicationContext;
    }

    public IQueryable<PushTemplate> PushTemplates => _applicationContext.PushTemplates;

    public void Save(PushTemplate pushTemplate)
    {
        if (pushTemplate.PushTemplateId == 0)
        {
            _applicationContext.PushTemplates.Add(pushTemplate);
        }
        else
        {
            PushTemplate dbEntity = _applicationContext.PushTemplates.Find(pushTemplate.PushTemplateId);

            dbEntity.Messages = new List<PushTemplateMessage>();

            _applicationContext.SaveChanges();

            dbEntity.Messages = pushTemplate.Messages;

        }

        _applicationContext.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Database context:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext
{
    private readonly string _connectionString;

    public DbSet<PushTemplate> PushTemplates { get; set; }
    public DbSet<PushTemplateMessage> TemplateMessages { get; set; }
    public ApplicationDbContext(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        _connectionString = configuration.GetConnectionString("MakeAppDb");
    }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseNpgsql(_connectionString, b => b.MigrationsAssembly("MakeAppPushesNet_2"));
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        modelBuilder.Entity<PushTemplate>()
            .HasMany(x => x.Messages)
            .WithOne(y => y.PushTemplate)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
    }
}
```

And finally call to update operation from my controller:

```
PushTemplate pushTemplate = new PushTemplate
{
        Messages = pushTemplateMessages // new list of messages
}; 

_pushTemplateRepository.Save(pushTemplate);
```

After this operation I have the old `PushTemplateMessage` and new version of `PushTemplateMessage`. But I need only new one! As you can see, in the repository I have tried to 'clean' old `PushTemplateMessage`s to set then new list. But it continues to merge old data with new! Where is the mistake?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I have solved it. This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12828739/entity-framework-set-navigation-property-to-null) was helpful. This is from the answer.

So, if you want to synchronize (not add), even if you want set new values as `NULL` you have to use `include("EntityName")` on your db context. Now my save/update repository code is:

```
    public void Save(PushTemplate pushTemplate)
    {
        if (pushTemplate.PushTemplateId == 0)
        {
            _applicationContext.PushTemplates.Add(pushTemplate);
        }
        else
        {
            PushTemplate dbEntity = _applicationContext.PushTemplates
                .Include(x => x.Messages)
                .FirstOrDefault(x => x.PushTemplateId == pushTemplate.PushTemplateId);

            dbEntity.Messages = pushTemplate.Messages;

        }

        _applicationContext.SaveChanges();
        }
```

As you can see I just use `Include()`. And now I can set `null` or synchronize it with a new list of values.