# Set virtual property to null only works while debugging

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I`m working with an ASP.Net Web Forms Application.

I have an Entity `Booking` with a Property `public virtual Reason Reason` which can be set over a dropdown-control.

The exisiting code (ascx.cs-File) goes like this:

```
if(DropdownReasonState.Enabled)
  var booking.Reason = booking.bookingState == BookingState.Booked ? DropdownReasonState.SelectedValue() : null;
```

If the state is set to `Booked`, it works perfectly fine. If the State is something else than `Booked` booking.Reason is not set to `null`. Instead the previous reason of the entity persists, which leads to faulty behaviour.

If I do something like this, so I can debug it:

```
if(DropdownState.Enabled){
   if (booking.BookingState == BookingState.Booked)
       booking.Reason = DropdownReasonState.SelectedValue();
   else
       booking.Reason = null;
}
```

it works - but only if I debug into the else-part. Otherwise the else part is hit but Reason is never set to `null`.

Why is it only working if I am debugging it?

Comment: It sounds like you are asking why `booking.bookingState == BookingState.Booked` is always true?   Perhaps it is.

Comment: No, I am asking, why `booking.Reason = null` is not `null`. I did the following. I've put a breakpoint on the line where `Reason` is set to null, the breakpoint gets hit and it works. If I remove the breakpoint, the `Reason`-Value is not set to `null` and remains in the previous state, even though the test-case is exactly the same.  I've put an counter before `booking.Reason=null` and tracked if the line is actually it and verified in that way, that the else-part is hit and the value actually should be `null`. This makes absolutly no sense to me!

Comment: Is `booking.Reason` really `null` **after** the line is executed? I suspect that `null` isn't a valid value for this property and it just gets swallowed. How is the set accessor for `Reason` implemented? Print the value of `booking.Reason` before and after you changed it to your output stream and see if it changes.

Comment: I`ve digged a little bit deeper and my problem is a duplicate of this `https://stackoverflow.com/a/12834578/10781626` and it is already answered. Nevertheless thanks for the response!